# Scala test eventually configuration for all implementations?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have many many tests that runs with asynchronous code in scala, I am working with scala concurrent eventually. This helps me to know when given a certain asynchronous event happens I can expect certain values.

But eventually has a timeout that can be overwritten for each test so it does not crash expecting for a value that is not there yet...

I would like to change this timeout for all the implementations of eventually with one configuration change for all the tests.

In terms of code I do the following:

```
class AsyncCharacterTest extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with Eventually
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with ResponseAssertions {
  "Should provide the character from that where just created" should {
    val character = Character(name = "juan", age = 32)
    service.createIt(character)
    eventually(timeout(2.seconds)){ 
      responseAs[Character] should be character
    }
  }
}
```

I would like not to have to write this timeout(2.seconds) for each test... I would like to have a configuration for all the tests with the chance to override this timeout for specific cases.

Is this possible with scala concurrent eventually? this would help me to write more DRY code.

Doing something like

```
Eventually.default.timeout = 2.seconds
```

And then this is working for all the tests at the same time with 2 seconds by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, what you currently do by `eventually(timeout(...))`) is provide an explicit value to an implicit parameter.

One simple way to achieve what you want would be to do the following:

1. *Remove* all the explicit `timeout()` from `eventually call.
2. Create a trait to contain a desired default value for the timeout as an implicit value:

   ```
    trait EventuallyTimeout {
     implicit val patienceConfig: PatienceConfig = PatienceConfig(timeout = ..., interval = ...)
   ```

   }
3. Mix this trait in into all of your tests:

   ```
    class AsyncCharacterTest extends WordSpec extends EventuallyTimeout extends ...
   ```

Full example:

```
// likely in a different file
trait EventuallyTimeout {
    implicit val patienceConfig: PatienceConfig = PatienceConfig(timeout = ..., interval = ...)
}

class AsyncCharacterTest extends WordSpec
  with Matchers
  with Eventually
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with ResponseAssertions 
  with EventuallyTimeout {
      "Should provide the character from that where just created" should {
        val character = Character(name = "juan", age = 32)
        service.createIt(character)
        eventually { 
          responseAs[Character] should be character
        }
      }
}
```

For more details, refer to [`Eventually` docs](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.17/org/scalatest/concurrent/Eventually.html) and [implicit](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html).

Finallly, on a side note, `eventually` is mostly intended for integration testing. You might want to consider using different mechanisms, such as:

1. `ScalaFutures` trait + `whenReady` method - similar to `eventually` approach.
2. Async* spec counterparts (ie. AsyncFunSpec, AsyncWordSpec, etc.).

Comment: This isn't exactly right (judging by the documentation you linked): `eventually(){...}` doesn't compile as the implicit clause is actually the last (as it must be), so should be `eventually { ... }`. Also, the implicit parameter should be of type `PatienceConfig`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @TzachZohar Yep, I was writing that without access to compiler and off top off my head - fixed already, but thanks for the heads up anyway.